# Rotating monitor from landscape to portrait in Win7? HP w2207h monitor

Tags: graphics-card, display, rotate

I have an HP w2207h monitor, which supposedly has the option to rotate the screen 90 degrees.  I have rotated the monitor, but the screen stays the way it was.  I have the most recent drivers for the monitor and still no dice (driver 3.0).

How can I rotate my screen?  I have downloaded apparently all the software and nothing works.  Apparently, some people have an option in display settings to change the orientation, but not I.

**edit:** I have an nVidia card, made for a laptop.  This is running on a laptop with a broken screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rotating feature is not usually activated by physically rotating the monitor, but in the software that comes with your video card. These auto-sensing monitors are available I believe, but I don't think your monitor is one of them unfortunately.

For NVIDIA cards, check out the NVIDIA control panel:

[image]

For ATI cards, use the Catalyst Control Center:

[image]

For Intel graphics, see the Graphic properties:

[image]

Sometimes the rotate feature will be integrated into display settings as you have mentioned, under a tab named after your card (will be a bit different on Windows 7).

Comment: the nVidia image doesn't load for me, try this: http://www.realtimesoft.com/multimon/reviews/3mon_gf4/nview_rotate_display.png

Comment: Was adding that one to the bottom, its a different image actually, I'll tinypic it.

Comment: It is an intel card, and I don't get the above option.  This might be because I'm running off of a laptop with a cracked screen.  So it is a laptop video card, pushing the screen to just my monitor.  Would this complicate things?

Comment: there are usually hotkeys as well, but since that display is a pivot screen, i think you would need to 'rotate' the mouse as well, wouldn't you?

Comment: You don't have this option in the Screen Resolution dialog: http://img.labnol.org/di/dualmonitors.png ?

Comment: @John, no I don't.  @Mollu, yes I would.  I've been told to try alt-left arrow but that didn't do anything.

Comment: You can give this software example from Microsoft a try: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms812499.aspx It uses C# so you'll need the .NET framework, the example can be downloaded from here: http://download.microsoft.com/download/b/f/3/bf321ec9-f3a7-473f-ba1b-7f9ea8949d27/displaysettingscodesample.exe I've compiled it for you here: http://www.mediafire.com/?emoxmnyooy2

Answer (score 2):

From the makers of **PowerStrip** comes this handy little utility:

**[iRotate](http://www.entechtaiwan.com/util/irotate.shtm)** provides convenient access to the native rotation capabilities present in contemporary display drivers, via a popup menu accessible from the system tray and optional system-wide hotkeys. It's no longer necessary to resort to bloated Windows hacks, additional software layers or phantom drivers to achieve content rotation. In most instances, support is now available directly from the graphics chip manufacturers, who continuously improve and apply quality assurance to their drivers.

By leveraging the native rotation capabilities now provided by ATI, **nVidia**, Intel, Matrox, S3, XGI and others, iRotate offers exceptional speed and efficiency, with minimal impact on scarce system resources - the entire iRotate package, including installation, documentation, and native language support in all the major European and Asian languages, weighs in at only 125kb. And like all EnTech graphics utilities, iRotate supports multiple graphics cards from various vendors, simultaneously, under every multi-monitor enabled operating system from Windows 98 to Vista.

*... and indeed Windows 7.*

[image]

*iRotate is freeware.*

If you want to "rotate" the mouse as well, you can also try this:

**[EeeRotate](http://vk.edward.li.googlepages.com/eeerotate)** - A tiny program to rotate your screen and touchpad or mouse at the same time. Especially designed for EeePC but **should work with all computers**.

**Ctrl + Alt + Right**: rotate screen and touchpad or mouse by 270 degrees

**Ctrl + Alt + Up**: back to normal

EeeRotate conveniently combines **iRotate** with **[SakasaMouse](http://download.cnet.com/SakasaMouse/3000-2056_4-10553398.html)**.

*EeeRotate is freeware and can be used portable.*

Edit: i just tested it with an ATI card, it works.

Answer (score 0):

In Win7, if you right-click on the background and pick "Screen Resolution", you should get a dialog which has "Orientation" among the options, letting you pick Landscape or Portrait. This should make it easy to configure the way you want.

Comment: I think that's the problem. He said he doesn't have this option unfortunately. Maybe he's looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Yeah - but it's not really clear that the option is in the Screen Resolution section. In earlier versions of Windows it was in a different place.

Comment: This option isn't available.

Comment: Ok, yup. So I it sounds like the driver isn't reporting it as an available option. Since you have the latest driver, you may be needing a support call to HP.

Answer (score 0):

The option appeared for me after I changed to the native resolution of my screen (highest it will go), then rebooted.  Windows display dialog would not give me that option until after I did those 2 things in that sequence.