# Low level support for rotating an external monitor

Tags: windows-xp

I'm using a laptop with a relatively large external monitor. About the laptop one I cannot do anything, and it being rather small, nor do I want to, but the external monitor is quite large, and nowadays all of them being almost twice as wide as they're tall, I would like to turn it by 90 degrees.

A lot of my time at work goes to staring at text files, and the vertical dimension is significantly more important than the horizontal one.

Presuming I can rotate and fixate it so it stays in the upright position, what software would I need to use to support that rotated state? It would obviously need to be rather low level since every application in windows would need to be rotated by 90 degrees.

***All ideas and any possible experience in doing something like this are welcomed ! :)***

My laptop is HP 6715s with an ATI graphics adapter which supposedly supports monitor rotation (as in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/97135/rotating-monitor-from-landscape-to-portrait-in-win7-hp-w2207h-monitor) first answer's screenshot, but upon rotation and clickling apply nothing happens, and it goes back to normal landscape mode). Have no idea what is up with that :-/

Answer (score 1):

The ATI graphics adapter's software should have a "rotate" option.  After clicking apply, there should be a conformation box, to ensure that the monitor still functions.  Make sure to press OK.

If you do not see a conformation box, and your screen goes black, your probably doing something wrong.
Post a screenshot of your graphics card settings if this is the case.

Comment: Try holding Cntrl+Shift+LeftArrowKey.

Comment: A screenshot of my graphics card settings - where are those situated?

Comment: I'll post a screenshot of the my ati control center tomorrow (I'm not on that computer right now).